# AspectJ matching Annotated classes but not its child classes

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj

I want to configure transaction on my DAOs parent class and prohibit that a concrete DAO has its own transaction config, so I use Springs `@Transactional`:

```
@Transactional(/* some transactionConfig */)
abstract class AbstractDao
{
    //...
}

// this is ok
class UserDao extends AbstractDao
{
    //...
}

@Transactional (/* some other config*/) // this should be illegal
class DocumentDao extends AbstractDao
{
    //...
}
```

I use AspectJs `@DeclareError` to enforce my design rules. When I use the followint error and pointcut declaration I get errors also on the code in the (legal) UserDao as it inherits the Annotation from AbstractDao.

```
@Pointcut("call(*.new(..)) || call(* *(..)) || set (* *) || get (* *)")
public void doAnything()
{
    // no code
}

@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional *) && doAnything()")
public void transactionalClass()
{
    // only pointcut, no code
}

@Pointcut("within(AbstractDao+) && !within(AbstractDao)")
public void inDao()
{
    // no code
}

@DeclareError("transactionalMethod() && doAnything() && inDao()")
public static final String TRANSACTIONAL_NOT_ALLOWED =
        "@Transactional of this method is not necesarry, we have it on class level in AbstractDao";

@DeclareError("transactionalClass() && inDao() && doAnything()")
public static final String ERROR = "Transactional is not allowed on method level";
```

Is it possible to match only classes that are explicitelty annotated (in this example the `DocumentDao`)?

Answer (score -1):

So, I think you are looking to capture uses of @Transactional on methods or classes in sub-classes of `AbstractDao`.  Assuming this is the case, the following should work:

```
@Pointcut("within(AbstractDao+) && !within(AbstractDao)")
public void inDao()
{
    // no code
}

@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional *)")
public void transactionalClass()
{
    // no code
}

@Pointcut("withinCode(@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional *.*(..))")
public void transactionalMethod()
{
    // no code
}

@DeclareError("(transactionalMethod() || transactionalClass()) && inDao()")
public static final String TRANSACTIONAL_NOT_ALLOWED = "NOT ALLOWED!";
```

I have not actually tried this out, and so you may need some tweaking of the pointcuts, but this is the kind of thing that should work.

---

**EDIT**: a more succinct answer is this:

```
pointcut transactionsNotAllowed() : (within(@Transactional AbstractDao+) || 
  execution(@Transactional * AbstractDao+.*(..))) && !within(AbstractDao);
```

This should work for you. It uses code-style aspectj syntax, which I find much more intuitive.

Comment: That was my first idea bit transactionaClass matches on all DAO classes as they inherit from AbstractDao which has the @Transactional annotation, not only those classe that have an explicit annotation.

Comment: I don't follow you.  Although transactionaClass matches on all DAO objects, the final pointcut is restricted so that only subclasses of DAO are considered. But anyway, I prefer the second answer below.